# How to duplicate STDOUT?

Tags: bash, stdout

To put it lean and mean, how to duplicate something like:

```
echo 'hello'
```

to `STDOUT` and a file?

Like:

```
echo 'hello' 1>&0 | echo ... # and then?
```

Answer (score 11):

Look up the `tee` program.

`man tee`:

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files.

Also, you can chain this program if you need multiple files, etc.

`> echo "hello" | tee /tmp/h1.txt`
hello
`> cat /tmp/h1.txt`
hello